# How to iterate through a char* in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm new to assembly language. My question is simple, how do I iterate through a char* of unknown size using a loop in assembly language? An example would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What architecture? Assembly language exists for every processor (x86, MIPS, ARM, etc.)

Comment: The architecture is x86.